# -bash: dev/null: No such file or directory - at startup

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

when you run the OS gives this error.The file exists, but it is empty. I tried this command, but nothing changes. `sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3`

Answer (score 1):

If it says `dev/null` (not `/dev/null`, mind the leading slash), then it doesn't refer to `/dev/null`. It refers to `./dev/null`. This is different than `/dev/null`, unless the working directory happens to be `/`.

Some line probably misses the leading slash for `/dev/null`. You need to find it and fix it. The regex you need may be `[^/]dev/null`.

Your grep probably supports `-r`. I would first check the contents of `/etc/`:

```
sudo grep -r '[^/]dev/null' /etc/
```

And if by "when you run the OS" you mean "when your user logs in", then the home directory:

```
grep -r '[^/]dev/null' "$HOME"
```

(consider `--binary-files=without-match` if your `grep` supports it).

Similarly you can check other directories (e.g. `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`, although I would rather expect it to be sane).

As the last resort you may want to check the entire `/`. In this case an option to not descend to other filesystems may be handy. There is no such option in `grep` but you can use `find` with `-xdev`:

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -exec grep -l '[^/]dev/null' {} +
```

This last command doesn't use non-POSIX extensions, it's quite universal.

If any command finds something, you should carefully investigate if `/` is really missing there. False positives are possible. E.g. a string like `udev/null` or `udev/nullifier` (whatever it could refer to) is possibly fine, while `=dev/null` is possibly erroneous. And `/var/log/auth.log` *will* most likely contain the literal `[^/]dev/null` string, but it's just a log.

If you decide to alter any file you don't fully understand, make a copy of it (`cp -a`) and/or note (on a piece of paper) its path and what you're changing. Change one file at a time and reboot. If the problem doesn't vanish, change the file back to what it was. In case you break something very bad, such precautions may save your day. It's a worst case scenario though. You will probably narrow your search down to just one suspicious file and this will be it.